# Two forms of convolution

Tags: real-analysis

I have come across two forms of definition of convolution:

1.$h(x)=\int f(y)g(x-y)dy$

2.$h(x)=\int f(y)g(y-x)dy$

What's the difference between these two

Comment: The second is a correlation, not a convolution.

Comment: @OpenBall sorry I correct it

Comment: No, you mean $f \ast g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) g(x-y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-y) g(y)dy= g \ast f(x)$ : the convolution is commutative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression defines convolution. Notice how the arguments add to $x$. Convolution "spreads" each point of the function in the shape of the other function. Basically, it blurs the function with another function (in photography/optics, $g$ is known as a point spread function and defines how a point light source looks like instead of a single pixel).  A useful property is that fourier transform maps convolution to multiplication: $f\ast g \mapsto \mathcal{F}(f)\cdot \mathcal{F}(g)$.

The second defines correlation. It's basically a "dot product" of a function with a shifted version of the other function. Therefore it measures similarity (overlaps the functions with a shift and checks how much they resemble each other). In signal and image processing, it's used to fined a pattern - for instance, to find the delay between two signals or how much your optical mouse moved, based on two consecutive images of your desk. Fourier transform maps correlation to conjugated multiplication: $\operatorname{corr}(f,g)\mapsto \mathcal{F}(f)\cdot \overline{\mathcal{F}(g)}$.

They are distinct mathematical operations with different uses.

However, they are mathematically related, as you may have noticed. For symmetric functions, they are the same, and you get one from the other if you horizontally flip one of the functions. However, you should distinguish them by what you mean to use them for.

Comment: $f \ast g(x) = \langle f(.), g(x-.)\rangle$